# How to separate reducers into multiple NgModule?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

For Effects, I can separate like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EffectsModule.run(FooEffects)
  ]
})
export class FooModule {}


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EffectsModule.run(BarEffects)
  ]
})
export class BarModule {}
```

Then import these two modules in the `MainModule`.

Now I want to separate Reducers. Right now I puts all reducers in the `MainModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.provideStore(
      compose(
        storeFreeze,
        combineReducers
      )({
        foo: fooReducer,
        bar: barReducer
      })
    ),
    // ...
  ],
  // ...
})
export class MainModule {}
```

I tried this, but not work.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.provideStore({ foo: fooReducer })
  ]
})
export class FooModule {}
```

Is there a way to separate it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh just found the issue on GitHub.

Right now it is impossible, but is on plan.

Please track [here](https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues/211).